# Flutter bottom navigation bar items not aligned

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my newspaper app, the left-most bottom navigation bar item is always showing up at a higher position than the other items, it is not aligned.

[image]

You can see the `bookmark` icon is not aligned with the others. In fact, if I put any other icon in the first position, that icon is showing up at a higher position. The problem is with that first item no matter what icon I add there.

Code for the `BottomNavigationBar`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/main.dart';

BottomNavigationBar getBottomNavBar(themeProvider, context, appbarScrollController, refresh) {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    elevation: 3,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.bookmark,
            color: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          label: ""
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home_sharp,
            color: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          label: ""
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.subject,
            color: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          label: ""
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.video_collection,
            color: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          label: ""
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.more_horiz,
            color: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ),
          label: ""
      ),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      
    },
  );
}
```

I kept all the `labels` blank as I don't need them. It appears the same in all the screens with this alignment problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> If type is not specified, then it's automatically set to
> BottomNavigationBarType.fixed when there are less than four items,
> and BottomNavigationBarType.shifting otherwise.

And since you have more than 3 items, the type changed to  `BottomNavigationBarType.shifting` which shifts the selected item slightly upward.

Try this:

```
 BottomNavigationBar(
   type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
   ...
 )
```